# Django Help: How to take text data from textbox and pass through python script?

Tags: python, html, django, web

I'm making a Django web app where I want to take user input from an HTML textbox and run it through a python script. The script works when I input text from the command line, but I want to be able to make the web app print what happens to the text when it goes through the script.

I have already made a Django web app, and when the server is run a basic HTML page with a simple text box and a submit button appears (it's a form).

I have written a separate python script which will take user input (from the command line) and run the text entered through the script.

How would I be able to replace the input() from the function with form data from the HTML page?

An example of what I want to do:

```
<form action="">
text: <input type="text" name="handle" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The above is a simple form with the submit button. When the 'submit' button is pressed, I want that data to go to a script:

```
import statements

def blah():
screenname = input('Enter your name here: ') 
output = screenname.functionA
print(output)
```

Except the input() is replaced with the form data from the HTML file.

Where would I store the python script in the Django app?

How would I pass the text from the form to the python script?

Any help is appreciated, I'm trying to develop my web design abilities one step at a time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start with form. You will need to post that form to a django view:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  <inputs here ...>
</form>
```

Inside the view where you render that page you will need to check for method of the request and if it is a `POST` request, then pass it to the function.

```
def view_name(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    screenname = request.POST.get("handle", None)  # handle is the name of the input in the question.
    # Here you can do anything with your screenname, like passing it to the function.
  return render(request, 'path/to/form.html', {})
```

Now about putting your custom script inside django. One way will be adding utils.py script inside you app and calling `utils.blah(sreenname)` in previous code. Also instead of `print` you can return the result and show it:

```
from app_name.utils import blah
def view_name(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    screenname = request.POST.get("handle", None)
    result = blah(screenname)
    return render(request, 'path/to/result.html', {'result': result}
  return render(request, 'path/to/form.html', {})
```

Comment: In regards to the last bit of code: is that all in the Django view?

Comment: Yes. Think as Model View Controller logic, django is Model Template View type framework and this is work for View

Comment: What would the urls.py look like for the above example?

Comment: Same as any other view. Usually you always use `app_name.view_name` as view parameter. Check Django Docs for urls

Comment: When I enter a submission on the forum and hit enter, I am brought to a blank screen. The error I recieve on the console is:                                Method Not Allowed (POST): /
[19/Mar/2017 00:19:45] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Comment: Most likely you forgot to add `csrf_token` in your template form inside `<form>` tag: `<form method="POST" action="">{{ csrf_token }} other inputs here</form>`

Comment: No, I have the {{ csrf_token }} in the forum, that doesn't seem to be causing the issue. I am using a class-based view, if that has any effect.

Comment: And what is your urls.py line for that page?

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^result$', views.ResultPageView.as_view(), name='result')
] I am using class based views, HomePageView is the class for index.html with the form.

Comment: Everything is working great: I figured out the issue and was able to resolve it. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 I used this solution in my view.py file :
def view_name(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    screenname = request.POST.get("handle", None)  # handle is the name of the input in the question.
    # Here you can do anything with your screenname, like passing it to the function.
  return render(request, 'path/to/form.html', {})

but getting the unicode error as "'unicode' object has no attribute 'script1_'"

FYI below is my code:

<form id="modifySingleTag" name="ModifiedSingletag" method="post" >{% csrf_token %}
<div class="input-wrapper">
    <div class="title first">
        <span class="option">copy and paste the tag to modify here:</span>
        <textarea class="input_textarea" name="input_textarea1"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
 <button id="modifyButton" name="Modifytag" class="btn primary" type="submit" title="" value="Modify"> MODIFY</button>
</div>
</form>

View.py:

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['Modifytag'] == 'Modify':
       script1_ = request.POST.get("input_textarea1", None)
       print "I am script1 from Views.py".script1_
       modify_tag(script_=script1_, dimension='320X568', os_='ANDROID')
       print "the script from single tag view". script1_
    return render(request, 'home/index.html')
```

Comment: You might consider adding a few explanatory sentences as this increases the value of your answer for other users. :)